# NoSuchToken exception for StringTokenizer.nextToken()

Tags: java, stringtokenizer, nosuchelementexception

When I try to run the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    class dothis {
      public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ride.in"));

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ride.out")));

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());

        String s1 = st.nextToken();    
        String s2 = st.nextToken();        
        char[] arr = new char[6];

        if (find(s1, arr, 1) == find(s2, arr, 1)) {
            out.print("one");
        } else {
            out.println("two"); 
        }

        out.close();                                  
      }
    }
```

With the data file:

```
    ABCDEF
    WERTYU
```

it keeps on outputting:

```
    Exception_in_thread_"main"_java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at_java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
        at_dothis.main(Unknown_Source)
```

I did see a similar question on Stack Overflow, but in that case, the second line of the text file is blank, therefore there wasn't a second token to be read. However, the two first lines of this data file both contain a String. How come a token would not be read for the second line?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the StringTokenizer class from the first line and so when you are setting the value of s2, there is no token left because s1 has the first and only token (ABCDEF). If I am not wrong, you are getting the exception when you are trying to set s2?

Answer (score 0):

the [`StringTokenizer` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String)) say that if you don't pass a token delimiter in the constructor, it's assumed to be:

> " \t\n\r\f": the space character, the tab character, the newline character, the carriage-return character, and the form-feed character

.  you're then asking for two tokens to be read out of the string returned by `f.readLine()`, which is `ABCDEF` (with no delimiters), so an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a line it will return a String till it found "\n" or "\r" and in your case you have token in each line (i believe).

You really don't need StringTokenizer.

Each line you read is actually a token for you.

Also, if you are expecting each-line to have more than one token than you need to make sure you supply the delimiter to your tokenizer to understand the same.
StringTokenizer uses the default delimiter set, which is " \t\n\r\f": the space character, the tab character, the newline character, the carriage-return character, and the form-feed character. Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready for Java 7/8, you could make it even simpler without the need of StringTokenizer.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

class dothis {
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("ride.in")));
    String[] lines= contents.split("\n");

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ride.out")));

    String s1 = lines[0];    
    String s2 = lines[1];        
    char[] arr = new char[6];

    if (find(s1, arr, 1) == find(s2, arr, 1)) {
        out.print("one");
    } else {
        out.println("two"); 
    }

    out.close();                                  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());//f.readLine() method reads only 1 line

String s1 = st.nextToken();    
String s2 = st.nextToken();//there is no second line, so this will give you error
```

Try this:

```
   String result = "";
    String tmp;
    while((tmp = f.readLine())!= null)
    {
        result += tmp+"\n";
    }
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(result);

    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

    int count = st.countTokens();
    for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
    {
        str.add(st.nextToken());
    }
```

Now check by using the above arraylist.

As StringTokenizer is depricated, it is suggested to use split() method of String class.